# Q learning: overtraining and converagence

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm working on a Q learning model to autopilot Flappy Bird (follow http://sarvagyavaish.github.io/FlappyBirdRL/): it manage to reach a good score like 500 after a while of training:

[image: beginning of the training]

But after longer training time, it doesn't score any better:

[image: longer training]

Finally it converges terribly that the bird can barely fly through the 1st pipe.

[image]

pseudo code:

```
Initialize Q arbitrarily
Repeat (for each episode):
    Initialize S
    Repeat (for each frame of episode):
        A ← f(Q, S) // compute action according to Q and current state
        Q(S, A) ← (1-α)*Q(S,A) + α*[reward + γ*maxQ(S',a)] // update Q(S, A)
        // reward = 1 for survival, reward = -100 for death
        S ← S' 
    until S is terminal
```

Here's the key updating strategy:

```
Q(S, A) ← (1-α)*Q(S,A) + α*[reward + γ*maxQ(S',a)]
```

every frame, $Q(S, A)$ update according to itself, `reward` of current frame and maximum `Q` value of next possible state: `-1000` if dead, `1` if alive.

Intuitively, I believe the problem is **my strategy backpropagates too shallow (or too slow)**: for every frame $t$, only $Q(S_{t-1}, A)$ is updated. It would takes at least $t$ episode to backpropagate until $Q(S_0, A)$ is updated. Considering randomness and reproducibility it could only takes much longer.

I try comparing my code with [deep Q learning paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf):

[image]

They sample random minibatch of transitions from a replay memory but for mine, I update the 1-step previous state only. And this is confusing me: how do I update `Q value` for $S_t$ when $S_{t+x}$ is the terminal state, whose `Q value` is accessible?

I guess it's in this equation but I don't understand:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes my intuition was right: the Q-value updating is wrong.

I shouldn't update Q-value every frame. In fact it would never affect the whole action sequence this way.

The correct updating strategy: maintain a `state-sequence` to record `(state, action)` for every frame. When it's terminal, propagate backward to update Q-value for every `(state, action)`:

```
Q ← {}
state-seq ← []

for each round:
    for each frame:
        S ← current state
        if S in Q:
            if Q(S, flap) > Q(S, do-nothing):
                A ← flap
            else:
                A ← do-nothing
        state-seq ← state-seq + [S, A]

        if terminal:
            for [S, A] in reversed(state-seq):
                if S is the 1st (closest to terminal):
                    Q(S, A) ← (1 - α) * Q(S, A) + α * R
                else:
                    S' ← next state of S
                    Q(S, A) ← (1 - α) * Q(S, A) + α * {R + γ * max[Q(S', flap), Q(S', do-nothing)]}
            state-seq ← []

α: learning rate
γ: discount factor
R: reward
       +1 for survival
    -1000 for death
```

old strategy:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

new strategy:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It converges much better and it scores higher than 10000 sometimes.